# typescript: custom return type in redux's dispatch

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a middleware for API in which I return the data fetched from the server. for example when I run:

```js
const fetchUsers = ()=>({
  type: 'FETCH_USERS'
})
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const users = await dispatch(fetchUsers())
```

type of users object is the same as the return type of `fetchUsers` function. But what I expect is the list of the users. Also, typescript keeps complaining `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression`. But in my middleware, it returns a promise that resolves to list of users.

So, how can I define the return type for a dispatch function?

I used

```js
const users = (await dispatch(fetchUsers())) as unknown as User[]
```

as a workaround.

UPDATE:
my middleware defined as:

```js
const apiMiddleware = store => next => async action => {
  next(action)
  // asynchronously fetch data from API using axios or whatever
  return next({type:'FETCH_USERS_RESULTS', data:data})
}
```

so it will return a promise that will resolve to completely new action.

Comment: can you provide was the `fetchUsers` does as code?

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: @ShivamSingla No.

Comment: In that case `dispatch` is a synchronous function and returns the action object itself. So, `await` has "no effect". So, `users` will not be the result.

Comment: read the update section.

Comment: @AliKazemkhanloo You want to use redux-thunk for this. It offers more control over async stuff than your middleware approach (you'd have one middleware doing all async data fetching which is bad design).